# Shortcut for Copy/Paste not work in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now I'm using the latest Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 20.04 and face the problem with the Copy/Paste shortcut. When I use Ctrl+C, it is not Copy the chosen code to the clipboard, it has been changed to Insert mode instead. And I even not be able to use Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V.
I have tried to reinstall the program but the problem still there. With other IDE, it still works normally.
So, please help to fix this problem!

Comment: I would try to navigate to "File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts" and search for "ctrl+c" and see what shows up. Perhaps you have installed an extension which overrides default behaviour?

Comment: in the keybinding dialog go to the top right and press **Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)**, find the faulty keybinding, not likely that an extension defines Ctrl+C as binding for the editorFocus

Comment: I have encountered the same thing in Debian Buster running as a container in a Chromebook. Somehow nothing is actually pasted when I copy paste between two vscode windows via CTRL+X and CTRL+V, (or using the equivalent controls of right click and manually selecting Cut and Copy from the drop-down menu).

Answer (score 7):

look at

```
File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcut
```

Or

```
Press Ctrl+k Ctrl+s
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but every key binding still normal for all. But when edit code it does not follow anymore

Answer (score 3):

You may well be experiencing this bug... https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124296

Answer (score 2):

You might have Ctrl+C assigned to multiple commands. Just right click on any file to go to the last option - Command Pallete, type the command Copy and see what other extension is using Ctrl+C which is not related to copying, and just remove the command from that extension. Also if you right click on any file that contains cody / text you should see the the command Ctrl+C assinged to the option copy.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall **vim** in extension of vs code.

1. Go to extension of vs code
2. You see a list of extension you have installed in vs. You should scroll through for vim extension.
3. click on **vim** extension.
4. click on uninstall.

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I am also on Ubuntu, but version 22.04. For me, it was an extension causing ctrl + c to no longer copy.  Look at your extensions and see what shortcut keys they have mapped. Or just disable each extension and try to copy/paste until it works and then you'll have your culprit.